# Ruby: making a caesar's cipher

Tags: ruby, iteration

So I am trying to iterate through a string and replace the each alphanumeric character based on the offset.

I want something like this:

"abc 123 !@#$%" with an offset of

1: "bcd 234 !@#$%"

2: "cde 345 !@#$%"

The problem with my code is that it will not modify the string.

```
alphabets = [*?a..?z] #makes an array of all the alphabets
    digits = [*?0..?9] #makes an array of all the single digits

    puts "offset?"
    offset = gets.chomp.to_i
    puts "string?"
    string = gets.chomp

    string.each_char do |character|

        if character[/[a-zA-Z]/] == character #checks if the character is an alphabet
            char_index = alphabets.index(character) + offset #gets the index of the current character being iterated and adds the offset
            #if the (index + offset) % 26 > 0, that means that the index is beyond 25. 
            #Then it will find the remainder and apply that as the new index
            char_index = char_index % 26 if char_index % 26 >= 0 
            character.sub!(character, alphabets[char_index]) #replaces the character with the offset character 
        elsif character[/\d/] == character #checks if the character is a number
            char_index = digits.index(character) + offset 
            char_index = char_index % 10 if char_index % 10 >= 0
            character.sub!(character, digits[char_index])
        end
        #if the character is neither an alphabet nor a number, nothing will run for that character
    end

    puts string
```

Comment: be specific about the problem you are having

Comment: The program is printing the original string, rather than modified string.

Comment: You are just changing the character, but not replacing it on the original string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just changing the character, but not replacing it on the original string. You could create a **modifiedString** and append the corresponding character after each modification (or not):

```
modifiedString << character
```

### Code:

```
alphabets = [*?a..?z] #makes an array of all the alphabets
    digits = [*?0..?9] #makes an array of all the single digits

    puts "offset?"
    offset = gets.chomp.to_i
    puts "string?"
    string = gets.chomp
    modifiedString = ""
    string.each_char do |character|

        if character[/[a-zA-Z]/] == character #checks if the character is an alphabet
            char_index = alphabets.index(character) + offset #gets the index of the current character being iterated and adds the offset
            #if the (index + offset) % 26 > 0, that means that the index is beyond 25. 
            #Then it will find the remainder and apply that as the new index
            char_index = char_index % 26 if char_index % 26 >= 0 
            puts"#{character} + #{alphabets[char_index]}"
            character.sub!(character, alphabets[char_index]) #replaces the character with the offset character 
            modifiedString << character
        elsif character[/\d/] == character #checks if the character is a number
            char_index = digits.index(character) + offset 
            char_index = char_index % 10 if char_index % 10 >= 0
            puts"#{character} + #{digits[char_index]}"
            character.sub!(character, digits[char_index])
            modifiedString << character
        else
                    modifiedString << character
        end
        #if the character is neither an alphabet nor a number, nothing will run for that character

    end
    puts "Original String: " + string
    puts "Modified One: " + modifiedString
```

**Note:** I also print the character + modifiedCharacter to check what is happening.

**Note2:** Just to mention it, if character is not modified, you still have to append it to the modifiedString.

### IO Example:

```
offset?
2
string?
asdasf242t%&%$&$%&23ad
a + c
s + u
d + f
a + c
s + u
f + h
2 + 4
4 + 6
2 + 4
t + v
2 + 4
3 + 5
a + c
d + f
Original String: asdasf242t%&%$&$%&23ad
Modified One: cufcuh464v%&%$&$%&45cf
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

> The problem with my code is that it will not modify the string.

Because you *didn't* modify the string.

Consider this code:

```
string = "abcdef"
string.each_char do |character| 
  character = "A"
end
puts string #=> "abcdef"
```

As you can see, merely setting the variable `character` to `"A"` does not replace the corresponding character *in the original string*.

Now consider this:

```
string = "abcdef"
string = string.gsub(/./) do |character| 
  character.succ
end
puts string #=> "bcdefg"
```

That should give you some ideas.

Comment: Okay so I changed character.sub! into string.sub! to replace the original string but it will only work with alphabets. An offset of 1, for example,  

"abc" >> "bcd"  
"hello 123" >> "jgnnq 543"

Comment: I'm not planning to write your code for you. I'm _teaching_ you, showing a general strategy for how to change each character. What you change it to is up to you.